# Cannot write after granting rwx permissions to group using an ACL

Tags: centos, permissions, acl, accounts

I have a user `bob` and he is a member of the group `developers`.

I want all developers to be able to read, write and execute on the directory `/home/testing` and all sub-directories. The directory `/home/testing` is owned by the user `testing` and belongs to the group `testing`.

To do this, I did the following:

```
# Create the developers group and add bob to it
groupadd developers
useradd -G developers bob

# Clear out any existing ACLs recursively
setfacl -Rb 

# Give the developers group read, write and execute permissions recursively (and by default) on the selected directory and all subdirectories.
setfacl -Rdm g:developers:rwx /home/testing
```

After making these changes, I logged out and back in with the user `bob`. However, the user `bob` still cannot write to files located in `/home/testing` or any sub-directory. I get a permission denied error.

Running `getfacl` on `/home/testing` looks like this:

```
# file: home/testing
# owner: testing
# group: testing
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:developers:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Looks correct to me. Anyone know why I still get a permission denied error when writing to `/home/testing` with the user `bob`?

Answer (score 4):

Figured this one out on my own. Bit of a bone-headed mistake. I assumed that `setfacl -Rdm` would set the set the defaults **and** the active ACL permissions. But instead it only set the defaults.

This command was also necessary:

```
setfacl -Rm g:developers:rwx /home/testing
```

Running `getfacl` on `/home/testing` now returns the following:

```
# file: home/testing
# owner: testing
# group: testing
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:developers:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:developers:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

And no more permission denied errors when writing files.